# How to run a .exe from c# by passing arguments?

Tags: c#, process

I had tried this code but not sure if this is correct. The .exe file getting opened(partially) but not performing the action.

Please help me.

Code :

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\\Program Files\\SQL Sentry\\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer";
            startInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Program Files\\SQL Sentry\\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer\\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer.exe";
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\\Program Files\\SQL Sentry\\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer\\XMLFile1.xml";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            try
            {
                using (Process p = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    p.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e17)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("17");
                MessageBox.Show(e17.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'partially'? Can you debug the application that is called?

Comment: Is it giving an exception? Is it performing something partially? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Does it require elevated privileges?

Comment: Just a gues but have you tried: `@"""C:\Program Files\SQL Sentry\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer\XMLFile1.xml""";` escaping the quotes? And since you are using verbatim you shouldn't escape the backslash.

Comment: The path as argument contains spaces, enclose it with extra double-quotes.

Comment: The application is getting opened but all the options that can be clicked are not visible or not clickable. Please let me know if am not clear

Comment: You should not be hard-coding paths. If that isn't the problem *this time*, it will be in the future. How do you know the path to the Program Files folder is `C:\Program Files`? It isn't on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double slash from your strings and place single quotes at the argument

```
 startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\SQL Sentry\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer";
 startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\SQL Sentry\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer.exe";
 startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 startInfo.Arguments = @"'C:\Program Files\SQL Sentry\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer\XMLFile1.xml'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the path to the file (argument) in single quotes:

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"'C:\\Program Files\\SQL Sentry\\SQL Sentry Plan Explorer\\XMLFile1.xml'";
```

You can always try to run the exe manually from command line to confirm that it works as expected.

Comment: Ya i tried it. It was working good if i used Command Line Arguments but giving some problem when i used the same values in c#.

Comment: When using verbatim string, escaping the backslash is not necessary.

Comment: And I have a question here, Can we assign a string value to startInfo.Arguments ? @Silvermind

Comment: @user3391849 Perhaps you can explain in detail by creating a new question on SO. Btw: Don't forget to upvote and accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe", "[arguments]");
```

more @ [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process)